# Property in Apache Camel

Tags: apache-camel

How i can add property name in url? I tried:

```
 <setProperty id="_setProperty1" propertyName="hashsum">
      <simple>${body}</simple>
 </setProperty>  

<to id="_to2" uri="http:{{host}{{port}}/pls/apex/edoapi/gk2/{{propert:hashsum}}"/>
```

But i get error:

> property.hashsum not found

Comment: See this FAQ where you need to use <toD> for dynamic-to: http://camel.apache.org/how-to-use-a-dynamic-uri-in-to.html

Comment: Your code has `{{propert:hashsum}}`.  There is a missing y in that. Could that be causing your issues?

Comment: I used <toD> and this helped me. Thanks for advice!